# cant import data mysql using sqoop import because of error

Tags: mysql, hadoop, rds, sqoop

When I tried import data from mysql in rds it was not working because of this error:

```
ERROR sqoop.Sqoop: Got exception running Sqoop: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not load db driver class: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not load db driver class: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
        at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.makeConnection(SqlManager.java:856)
        at org.apache.sqoop.manager.GenericJdbcManager.getConnection(GenericJdbcManager.java:52)
        at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.execute(SqlManager.java:744)
        at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.execute(SqlManager.java:767)
        at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.getColumnInfoForRawQuery(SqlManager.java:270)
        at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.getColumnTypesForRawQuery(SqlManager.java:241)
        at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.getColumnTypes(SqlManager.java:227)
        at org.apache.sqoop.manager.ConnManager.getColumnTypes(ConnManager.java:295)
        at org.apache.sqoop.orm.ClassWriter.getColumnTypes(ClassWriter.java:1833)
        at org.apache.sqoop.orm.ClassWriter.generate(ClassWriter.java:1645)
        at org.apache.sqoop.tool.CodeGenTool.generateORM(CodeGenTool.java:107)
        at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:478)
        at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:605)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:143)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:179)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:218)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:227)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:236)
```

I can't understand whats the error is as I,m fresher.I have `sqoop` jar file and mysql java connector jar in lib folder of sqoop.
Can any one please help me with this?

Comment: This question has been answered here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22741183/sqoop-could-not-load-mysql-driver-exception  Please refer to this link and let me know if you still face any issues

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sqoop: Could not load mysql driver exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22741183/sqoop-could-not-load-mysql-driver-exception)

Comment: Which mysql JAR do you you have? Because the class name for the JDBC driver might be different.

Comment: mysql-connector-java-5.1.31.jar

Comment: sqoop version 1.4.6

Comment: had  you  add your  mysql jar  to  sqoop_lib

Comment: yes i have added it