# Unable to load JDBC driver when running Sqoop import

Tags: mysql, hadoop, jdbc, sqoop

I created a SQL table and I am trying to import it data by using Sqoop to hdfs. But when I run `sqoop import` command, I am getting the following error.

This is the command:

```
hduser@ubuntu:~$sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://192.168.94.255/Cause_of_Death --table Death2014 --username root -P --target-dir /sqoop_out  -m 1
```

Result:

```
Warning: /home/hduser/sqoop-1.4.7.bin__hadoop-2.6.0/bin/../../hbase does not exist! HBase imports will fail.
Please set $HBASE_HOME to the root of your HBase installation.
Warning: /home/hduser/sqoop-1.4.7.bin__hadoop-2.6.0/bin/../../hcatalog does not exist! HCatalog jobs will fail.
Please set $HCAT_HOME to the root of your HCatalog installation.
Warning: /home/hduser/sqoop-1.4.7.bin__hadoop-2.6.0/bin/../../accumulo does not exist! Accumulo imports will fail.
Please set $ACCUMULO_HOME to the root of your Accumulo installation.
Warning: /home/hduser/sqoop-1.4.7.bin__hadoop-2.6.0/bin/../../zookeeper does not exist! Accumulo imports will fail.
Please set $ZOOKEEPER_HOME to the root of your Zookeeper installation.
19/12/20 02:54:21 INFO sqoop.Sqoop: Running Sqoop version: 1.4.7
Enter password: 
19/12/20 02:54:27 INFO manager.MySQLManager: Preparing to use a MySQL streaming resultset.
19/12/20 02:54:27 INFO tool.CodeGenTool: Beginning code generation
19/12/20 02:54:27 ERROR sqoop.Sqoop: Got exception running Sqoop: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not load db driver class: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not load db driver class: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.makeConnection(SqlManager.java:875)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.GenericJdbcManager.getConnection(GenericJdbcManager.java:59)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.execute(SqlManager.java:763)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.execute(SqlManager.java:786)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.getColumnInfoForRawQuery(SqlManager.java:289)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.getColumnTypesForRawQuery(SqlManager.java:260)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.getColumnTypes(SqlManager.java:246)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.ConnManager.getColumnTypes(ConnManager.java:327)
    at org.apache.sqoop.orm.ClassWriter.getColumnTypes(ClassWriter.java:1872)
    at org.apache.sqoop.orm.ClassWriter.generate(ClassWriter.java:1671)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.CodeGenTool.generateORM(CodeGenTool.java:106)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:501)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:628)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:147)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:76)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:183)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:234)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:243)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:252)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22741183/sqoop-could-not-load-mysql-driver-exception

Comment: No, I still have the same problem :(

Comment: Well, where did you install the mysql driver? Sqoop doesn't come with it

Comment: I install the mysql in linux